# simple javascript maths with strings - expected an error but got 'correct' result?

Tags: javascript, math

Fairly new to js and also trying to help teach my young nephew. I was explaining strings and numbers and how we can't do maths with strings. I explained how the + operator will concatenate strings so "3" + "3" results in "33".

But then we were testing other operators such as * and got correct results? I was expecting an error? And couldn't explain why it worked! So I'm here to find out why the below code works...

```
function sum(n) {
  var result = n * n;
  console.log(result);
}

sum("3");
```

Why does the console output 9?

Many thanks!

Comment: Using any math operator other than `+` will cause the js interperter to coerce the values to be numbers so that they then can be used in the operation

Comment: Multiplying converts strings to numbers, just because strings don't have that operator. See also https://stackabuse.com/javascript-convert-string-to-number

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are seeing is aligned with the EMACScript description for this kind of operations : https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator

If the operator is not `+` it then considers the operation to be numeric and tries to convert the arguments.